# Is working in a capital market company allowed?

Tags: sharia, work

I'm looking for a good job and I came to know about vacancies in company dealing in capital market. Will my income be halal if I work in that company?

Comment: I think you're not allowed to make a profit on money

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, according to the view of Shia, it won't be Haram if there is not any negative or haram ponit in the different jobs. Hence apparently the mentioned job is not Haram.
(of course if u r sure that the essence of the mentioned occupation is not haram either.

Comment: afaik, it is the same with sunni as well. As long as the company doesn't deal with haram, it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Any company that is interest-based or deals with taking and giving interest, it is not allowed to work for that company.  Even writing down or typing the interest transaction in computer is haram.  Because the prophet has cursed the taker of interest, the giver of interest, and the man involved in writing down the interest transactions.

Comment: You are assuming that the trade company deals with interest? That isn't the case on most trade companies (they deal with securities, bonds and stocks).